# How do I append a row with specific values to the output of my T-SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, append

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query which runs fine:

```
SELECT Id, Name from TravelAgency
```

The last row of the output of this query is shown below:

```
Id       Name
---      ----
---      ----
715      AB Ltd
```

I want to "manually" append the following values  to the result set of this query: (999, XY Ltd) so that running the modifed query will give me the following results:

```
Id       Name
---      ----
---      ----
715      AB Ltd
999      XY Ltd
```

To simplify, the query pulls the data requested from the TravelAgency table and ADDS the specified values at the end of the output. I need to add those specific values in my query but I just can't figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a union all:

```
select id, name from xxx -- is your query
union all
select 999 as id, 'XY Ltd' as name
```

EDIT:
In addition to @ThorstenKettner 's comment: If ID is not nummeric or for any reason you can not use it for the sort, then you could do it like this:

```
select ID, Name
from 
(
    select 1 as SpecialSort, ID, Name from xxx -- is your query
    union all
    select 2 as SpecialSort, 999 as ID, 'XY Ltd' as Name
) AllData
order by SpecialSort asc -- like this your manually added row will appear at the end
```

Comment: And if you want the additional record guaranteed to be at the end of the result set as requested, add an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause - probably simply `ORDER BY id` provided all real IDs are less than 999.

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION` to append your required entry along with return result set. It can avoid if the `999 XY Ltd` entry is already exists.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM TravelAgency
UNION 
SELECT 999 AS [Id], 'XY Ltd' AS [Name]
```

If the `999 XY Ltd` is already return form result set and allow the duplicate entries you can use `UNION ALL` and ensure the `999 XY Ltd` as last record by `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM (
    SELECT Id, Name FROM TravelAgency
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 999 AS [Id], 'XY Ltd' AS [Name]
) AS T 
ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: You don't need an outer query to apply the `ORDER BY`. Simply add the `ORDER BY` clause to your original query.